# Серверная сторона мобильного приложения

Tags: архитектура, мобильные-приложения

Надо сделать моб.приложение целью которого будет бесконечный просмотр новостей определенной тематики. Есть [Intel XDK](http://www.slideshare.net/Apps4All/intel-xdk-html5-intel) это платформа для разработки через JS, HTML и СSS, как осуществить серверную сторону? Можно ли тупо долбить через AJAX файлы php на сайте.

Comment: Понятия не имею как это делается через html+css+js, зато имею полное представление (и опыт кстати тоже) как это делать традиционным способом...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[@Zow](/users/4425/zow)](/users/4425/zow) добавляете `setInterval`, в котором будет происходить забор инфы с сайта чем угодно (лучше же конечно `ajax`, потому что удобней).

Проверяете, появились ли новые статьи (например вместе в `ajax` запросом отправляете номер последней полученной новости и сравниваете с последним номером на сервере). Если появились, то добавляете.

[[@Barmaley](/users/5648/barmaley)](/users/5648/barmaley) И да, не знаю, сколько эта поделка займет по времени традиционным способом, а вот на `html + js` вставить `ajax` модуль с методом `jQuery.append()`, который будет добавлять полученный текст в блок, займет меньше минуты.

Comment: Спасибо, но я просто отел спросить, нормально ли к php обращаться с приложения. Думал, там как-то своим способ делает через java или еще как то ?

Comment: @Zow думаю нормально. Во всяком случае я так делаю, пока не подводило))